# Problem with Laravel Policy method arguments count

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-authorization

I have following error when trying to authorize some `NewsPolicy`:

> Too few arguments to function App\Policies\NewsPolicy::create(), 1 passed in laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate.php on line 706 and exactly 2 expected

I have a `News` model under the namespace `App\Models` and a `NewsPolicy` under `App\Policies`.

Also I have custom `Gate::guessPolicyNamesUsing()` in my `AuthServiceProvider` with next callback:

```
Gate::guessPolicyNamesUsing(function ($modelClass) {
    return ['\\App\\Policies\\' . class_basename($modelClass) . 'Policy'];
});
```

I find out that *Laravel* for some reason removing the argument with the *model* class name at `Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate::callPolicyMethod()`:

```
protected function callPolicyMethod($policy, $method, $user, array $arguments)
{
    // If this first argument is a string, that means they are passing a class name
    // to the policy. We will remove the first argument from this argument array
    // because this policy already knows what type of models it can authorize.
    if (isset($arguments[0]) && is_string($arguments[0])) {
        array_shift($arguments);
    }

    if (! is_callable([$policy, $method])) {
        return;
    }

    if ($this->canBeCalledWithUser($user, $policy, $method)) {
        return $policy->{$method}($user, ...$arguments);
    }
}
```

But why my policy don't know what model they authorize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem is `viewAny` and `create` methods simply does not need second argument with model class.

It should look like this:

```
public function create(User $user)
{
    //
}
```